# Ball bounce angle in Java

Tags: java, coordinates, angle, bounce, pong

I have to make a ball rebound on a paddle, calculating where the ball rebounds: If it rebounds on a certain zone of the paddle, it must take a bounce angle of 20 degrees, in another zone a bounce angle of 45 degrees and at the center of the paddle a bounce angle of 0 degrees. The problem is that i have the same x and y variables for the ball and for the paddle, that derives from the same class "Entity", so i don't know how to work with coordinates to calculate the right zone where the ball rebounded. Can you help me? Thanks a lot and excuse me for my bad english.

```html
Class Entity:
/** The current speed of this entity horizontally (pixels/sec) */
protected double dx;

/** The current speed of this entity vertically (pixels/sec) */
protected double dy;

/** The current x location of this entity */ 
protected double x;

/** The current y location of this entity */
protected double y;
```

```html
Class Ball:
@Override
public void collidedWith(Entity other) 
{


    prm = y;
    
    if((prm>=50)&&(prm<=60))
    {
        alpha=0;
    }
    else if((prm>60)&&(prm<=80))
    {
        alpha=30;
    }
    else if((prm>80)&&(prm<=100))
    {
        alpha=45;
    }

    tan=Math.tan(alpha);
    dy=dx*tan;
    dx=-dx;
}
```

Comment: Add to your post what you've done so far.

Comment: I'm not sure to undersant what you want ? The impact point is : **x = ball.x + (ball.width / 2)** | **y = ball.y + ball.height** Considering 0,0 axis is a top left

Comment: I did it. I can't post the entire code 'cause it's too long, but those are only the parts of the code to understand. Thanks